# DynaTree root node null / undefined - children undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

```
("#tree").dynatree({                
minExpandLevel: 1,              
//persist: true,                
children: [{"title":"First Location",
"isFolder":true,
"expand":true,
"key":"location.92",
"icon":"location.gif",
"children":[{"title":"<span class='assetType'>First Location Child<\/span>",
"key":"locationid=92&typeid=1",
"expand":true,
"icon":"equipment.gif",
"children":[ (etc...)
```

So I do:

```
var rootNode = $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot");
var title = rootNode.data.title;

title = null
```

... ok, so I try:

```
var rootNode = $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot");
var node = rootNode.getChildren();
var title = node.data.title;
```

Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

If I just:

```
alert(node);
```

I get:

DynaTreeNode<location.92>: 'First Location'

So...?

And since I'm asking, in console:

```
jquery.dynatree.min.js:710:49:53.215 - Option 'title' is no longer supported.
```

?

Related?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null
ra
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rootNode is the (invisible) system root and `rootNode.data.title` is not set.
Since node.getChildren() returns a list, it should be

```
var rootNode = $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot");
var nodeList = rootNode.getChildren();
var title = nodeList[0].data.title;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have got the answer:

```
//node = item which has isFolder() = false, islazy() = false

var topnode = node.parent;
topnode.reloadChildren(function(topnode, isOk){});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the title using:

```
var rootNode = $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot");  
var realRootTitle = rootNode.childList[1].data.title;
```